# Find the selector that called the code block when using multiple selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to clean up my code. I have jquery code that toggles classes however some div elements have multiple of the same class. I have this:

```
       $(".core, .cloud, .sound").hover(function(){

           //NEED CODE HERE THAT WILL ALLOW ME TO SAVE THE
           //CURRENT CLASS(core,cloud or sound) AS A VARIABLE FOR USE BELOW
           //WITH THE EACH FUNCTION

    $(".core").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("outer-circle-large")) {
            $(this).removeClass( "outer-circle-large");
            $(this).addClass("outer-circle-large-hover");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass( "outer-circle-small");
            $(this).addClass("outer-circle-small-hover");
        }
    });
```

See the notes in the code for the section. Also what if I it was a and/or situation like the html elements were composed of 1 or more classes (.core and/or .sound and/or .clound). I tried this but it only selects one element.

Comment: Please clarify: "current" means an element which is being hovered?

Comment: Yes. Current is the current element that is being hovered which belongs to a certain group. (core, sounds, cloud);. I could write it the long way with a code block for each group however it seems like there should be another shorter way to write it since the code repeats.

Comment: Are you going to create `each()` functions for `.cloud` and `.sound`, too?

Comment: I would rather not. I could if need be. It looks like without the class name I will have to write a whole new hover for it too.

Comment: No. Just trying to get the idea. Frankly, adding a common class and using a data attribute for the type would be simpler. Can your HTML be changed? The problem is that you are likely to have more than one class on those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do, though it doesn't exactly answer your question...

```
<div class="myDivClass" data-whatever="core"></div>
<div class="myDivClass" data-whatever="cloud"></div>
<div class="myDivClass" data-whatever="sound"></div>

var myDivType = '';

$(".myDivClass").hover(function(){
    myDivType = $(this).attr('data-whatever');
});

$(".core").each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Note: I'm guessing you intended for the `each()` function to be inside the `hover()` function. I don't see how the variable helps otherwise.